# Bokeh highlight values in second plot and show data table

Tags: python, bokeh

I have two plots and a data table. I want to select a value in plot 1 and then the corresponding value of plot two should be highlighted in plot 2. In addition I would like to show a data table under both plots with the selected values. Here is what I have so far:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import show
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 3.280, 3.3925], [2, 3.3012, 3.4303], [3, 3.5972, 3.8696]]),
                   columns=['abspos', 'val1', 'val1_q'])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df2)

p1 = figure(title="Plot1",
            plot_width=1500,
            plot_height=900,
            x_range=[0, 5],
            y_range=[0, 5])

p1.circle('abspos', 'val1', source=source, line_color=None, color='red', size=6)

pq1 = figure(title="Plot2",plot_width=900, plot_height=900)
pq1.circle('val1_q', 'val1', source=source, line_color=None, size=6)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="abspos", title="abspos"),
        TableColumn(field="val1", title="val1"),
        TableColumn(field="val1_q", title="val1_q")
    ]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=300, height=280)


def plot_both(plot1, plot2):
    show(row(plot1, plot2))
    
    
plot_both(p1, pq1)
```

If I select the data point [2, 3.3012] in plot 1, the data point [3.3012, 3.4303] should be highlighted in plot 2. The data table underneath should show [2, 3.3012, 3.4303].

Question 1: How to achieve a highlight in plot 2 according to selected point in plot 1 (and vice versa).

Question 2: How to display a Table under both plots which shows the data of the selected data points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the tap tool (code below works for Bokeh v2.1.1)

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Row, Column, CustomJS, DataTable, TableColumn
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 3.280, 3.3925], [2, 3.3012, 3.4303], [3, 3.5972, 3.8696]]),
                   columns=['abspos', 'val1', 'val1_q'])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df2)

p1 = figure(title="Plot1",plot_width=900, plot_height=500, tools="tap,pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom,save,reset")
p1.circle('abspos', 'val1', source=source, line_color=None, color='blue', size=10)

p2 = figure(title="Plot2",plot_width=900, plot_height=500, tools="tap,pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom,save,reset")
p2.circle('val1_q', 'val1', source=source, line_color=None, color='blue', size=10)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="abspos", title="abspos"),
        TableColumn(field="val1", title="val1"),
        TableColumn(field="val1_q", title="val1_q")
    ]
dt1 = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=900, height=300)
dt2 = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=900, height=300)

show(Column(Row(p1, p2), Row(dt1, dt2)))
```

If you need more functionality you would need to add a JS callback like `p1.js_on_event('tap', CustomJS(args={...}, code="..."))`